# Password validation in angular 2, satisfying the following conditions:

Tags: javascript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

- Passwords must be at least seven (7) characters long and contain all
  of the following:
- At least one lower case letter (a, b, c, …z)
- At least one uppercase letter (A, B, C, … Z)
- At least one number (0, 1, 2, … 9)
- At least one special character (!, @, $, %, # …)

I tried the following :

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" for="passcode">Password *</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="passCode" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.passCode" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*\s).{7,12}$">
                    <div *ngIf="userAdd.controls['passCode'].hasError('required')&&(userAdd.controls.passCode?.dirty ||userAdd.controls.passCode?.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{errorMessageForRequired}}
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="userAdd.controls['passCode'].errors && userAdd.controls['passCode'].errors.pattern" class="alert alert-danger">
                        Passcode must contain only letters, numbers and underscores (7-12 characters)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please help me

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your [regex](https://regexr.com/38tvj) is a bit off.

Passes for: `Qwert!1` which meets requirements.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{7,64})" required placeholder="Qwert!1"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you., but how can I add custom validation for the same